# Transparent to color navbar on scroll doesn't switch to color when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsiveness

This code switches between a transparent and a white navbar depending on how far the page is scrolled. However, if I reload the page while it's scrolled to a point where the navbar should be white, it turns transparent again after it reloads until I start scrolling (then it turns white). How can I make it be white before I scroll if the page is reloaded?

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("nav").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("scrolled");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
        $("nav").addClass("scrolled");
      }else{
        $("nav").removeClass("scrolled");
      };
    
  
});
```

try this and give feedback

Comment: whats the error? try adding debugger; to find on console where the document ready function works or not

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comment to check scroll on load and set styles appropriately.

```js
function toggleScroll(){  
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $("nav").addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
    $("nav").removeClass("scrolled");
  };
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    toggleScroll();
    $( "nav" ).text( $(this).scrollTop() );
});

$(function() {
    toggleScroll();
    $( "nav" ).text( "Loaded with scroll: " + $(this).scrollTop() );
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.scrolled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav id="nav">
      Nav
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the oposite of what I want it to do. I want it to be transparent in the beginning and only turn white once I have scrolled down.

Comment: Edited to reverse the action and check scroll position on load.

Comment: It occurs to me that if your browser is restoring scroll position then the on-load check for scroll may be firing before the scroll position is restored by the browser which would account for the style not being set as you would expect. If this is the case you'll need to query `history.scrollRestoration` and account for it, either by setting it to `manual`, scrolling to the top of the page yourself, or running scroll check after it finishes restoring the previous scroll position.

Comment: Just tested this using a freestanding HTML document this is working in Safari and my above comment re: `history.scrollRestoration` doesn't seem to be the case. My posted example is working.